# How can I read an image from an android phone directory, rename it, and copy back to the same directory?

Tags: android

The piece of code I have written so far is as follow:

```
String fname = type + (i + 1) + "-" + ext;

String fname1 = type + (i + 2) + "-" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ext;

File file = new File(myDir, fname);

if (file.exists()) {

    //file.delete();

    continue;

} else {

    try {

        InputStream in = getResources().openRawResource(x);

        FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);

        byte[] buff = new byte[1024];

        byte[] buff1 = new byte[1024];

        int read = 0;

        try {

            while ((read = in.read(buff)) > 0) {

            outStream.write(buff, 0, read);

            //I wanted to fasten up the process so i added the code below: I have tried multiple way to do the same


            //FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(myDir+File.separator+fname);

            File File1 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator + 
            "Application"+File.separator + "/Images" + "Image1-.jpg");

            File File2 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator + "Application"+File.separator + "/Images" + fname1);

            //String name = in1.getName();

            File newname = new File(fname1);

            File1.renameTo(newname);

            FileUtils.copyDirectory(File1, File2);

        } 

finally {

    in.close();

    outStream.close();

}
```

However, this does not work.
Can anyone give me some advice on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can read images from directory by this-

```
file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "image.jpg");
```

call copyBack() function and pass file path and Name

```
 String shiftedPath = copyBack(file.getAbsolutePath(),newName);
```

// function use for copy and rename

```
public String copyBack(String srcPath,String newName) {
//you can defined path of same directory as per your requirement, and just pass new  
            file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "newName");
            file.mkdirs();
            try {
    //            File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    //            File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();

                String sourceImagePath = srcPath;
                String destinationImagePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
                File source = new File(sourceImagePath);
                destination = new File(file, ".image");
                if (source.exists()) {
                    FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(source).getChannel();
                    FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(destination).getChannel();
                    dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                    src.close();
                    dst.close();

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return destination.getAbsolutePath();
        }
```

Comment: Dear Nishchal, Thank you for replying....but this solution is not working. What i am trying to do in this app is: I am copying a image file from app resource to the device by making a new directory in the device. but it takes time. So, to improve the performance while i am copying the image from the app to the device, i am also picking up the first copied image from the device location and rename and paste it back into the same directory.